# How do I ensure that my startup program is run after the system tray is loaded?

Tags: c#, windows, system-tray

I have a windows forms application that is started from network login scripts.  This application uses a form that stays hidden but that has a `NotifyIcon` in the system tray.  The user interacts with the program using the `NotifyIcon` menus.  I'm running into the problem that when the scripts run the `NotifyIcon` will not show even though the process is running in the background.  Therefore the user has no idea whether or not the program is running or not.  This doesn't occur all the time but I believe it does happen when the application tries to start up before the system tray is ready.

How do I ensure that my startup program is run after the system tray is loaded?

Comment: Can't you simply refresh the NotifyIcon once every few seconds? (remove it and add it again)

Comment: Listen for the `TaskbarCreated` message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [System Tray Icon not appearing on startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858552/system-tray-icon-not-appearing-on-startup)

Comment: @RaymondChen Do you know of a way to easily test this aside from restarting by computer?  I've implemented the solution with TaskbarCreated in C# and when I tried testing by killing explorer.exe and restarting it my methods were called correctly.  However, I noticed that the icon was redrawn correctly even without my code.

Comment: Have you considered one or more virtual machines?