# Rare error on Tray icon creation, after a user log out / log in

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, system-tray, systray

I create a systray icon with:

```
BOOL TrayMessage(HWND hWnd, DWORD dwMessage)
{
    NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
    nid.cbSize = sizeof(nid);
    nid.hWnd = hWnd;
    nid.uID = 1;
    nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP;
    nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYAPP));
    lstrcpy(nid.szTip, L"MyApp");
    nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_NOTIFYICON;
    return Shell_NotifyIcon(dwMessage, &nid);
}
```

when the app starts / the window is created:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    if (!TrayMessage(hWnd, NIM_ADD))
        MessageBox(hMainWnd, L"Tray error.", 0, 0);
```

This error messagebox:

- never happens when I launch the .exe normally.
- only happens after a User Logout / User re-login, **once every 5 launches on average** (my app is automatically launched on every session startup with a TaskSchedular task)

Of course when the error happens, the icon isn't displayed in taskbar.

What could be the reason?

1. The systray system is not ready yet (very short after a user logout / login again) ?
2. The taskbar itself is not ready yet?
3. Should I move the creation to somewhere outside of `WM_CREATE`?

---

**Edit**: after @RbMm's comment, I tried this:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    TrayMessage(hWnd, NIM_ADD);
    // I removed MessageBox(...) from here
    uTaskbarRestart = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("TaskbarCreated"));
    ... 
    break;

default:
    if (message == uTaskbarRestart)
    {
        TrayMessage(hWnd, NIM_ADD);
        MessageBox(hMainWnd, L"TaskbarRestart", 0, 0);
    }
```

Result of this test: the cases for which the tray icon fails to be displayed are **exactly** the cases when the MessageBox `TaskbarRestart` is not shown, i.e. when TaskbarRestart event never comes to the message loop... That's strange...

Note: this only happens after a user logout / re-login.

Comment: you can register special message `s_uTaskbarRestart = RegisterWindowMessage(L"TaskbarCreated");` and every time when you got `s_uTaskbarRestart` - add taskbar icon. do this on `WM_CREATE` also. it can fail by 1.) reason - taskbar yet not created

Comment: @RbMm I tried this and added the result of the test in the question. Do you have an idea?

Comment: `TrayMessage` you need not always in `default` but only when `message == uTaskbarRestart` + on `WM_CREATE`. off course possible gap between `TrayMessage` (taskbar yet not created at this moment) and `RegisterWindowMessage` (taskbar already created, so you not receive message). you need **change order** - first call `RegisterWindowMessage` on `WM_CREATE` or better **at program startup** (this is global data, not related o window) and only after this `TrayMessage` on `WM_CREATE`

Comment: so in general in `entrypoint (WinMain, etc)` call `uTaskbarRestart = RegisterWindowMessage(L"TaskbarCreated");` (this must be **first** and **once**) and only then, on `WM_CREATE` and `message == uTaskbarRestart` call `TrayMessage`

Comment: @RbMm oh yes `TrayMessage` not always in `default:` but only if `message == uTaskbarRestart` + `WM_CREATE`, you're right, it was a wrong copy/paste. I edited the question. I'll try your new suggestion in your comments!

Comment: @RbMm I tried but no success until now. See here: the RegisterWindowMessage should be done during WM_CREATE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144179.aspx#Taskbar_Creation_Not

Comment: @RbMm No luck. I tried with `uTaskbarRestart = RegisterWindowMessage(L"TaskbarCreated");` in `WinMain`, before the main message loop. 75% of the time it works, but sometimes : 1. session log out  2. session log in   3. explorer starts   4. my apps starts hidden (no icon)  (I can see it in the process manager!)  5. no messagebox, it's like "TaskbarCreated" is never fired to my app :)  (75% of the time, the messagebox is displayed though!)

Comment: `he RegisterWindowMessage should be done during WM_CREATE:` - not off course. this is bad example. the `s_uTaskbarRestart` is global data by sense(not related to your window, look even in example it defined as `static`) must be initialize only once. the best place is program startup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149910/discussion-between-basj-and-rbmm).

Comment: this is very strange that you not receive `uTaskbarRestart` message in some case. i think it send to all top level window, however i not debug in detail this case - so can not just say why this happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of MSDN Shell_NotifyIcon doesn't show it anymore (such a shame!), but fortunately, there's an [archived version here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080919021338/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/bb762159.aspx) that gives two interesting informations:

1.

> Returns TRUE if successful, or FALSE otherwise. [...] 
>   You can call GetLastError for more specific information about a failure case. ***The most common cause of failure is that the taskbar window doesn't exist or is unresponsive***. GetLastError in that case returns E_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

2.

> **Handling Shell_NotifyIcon failure**
>   Shell_NotifyIcon will often fail when called during Windows startup (for instance, if your application is listed in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run. This appears to be because the system is busy starting applications. The failure is more common on low-spec computers or computers with some brands of antivirus software installed, which seem to be very intensive at startup.
>
> Unfortunately, you cannot rely on the error code returned by GetLastError. When Shell_NotifyIcon returns false, some of the common errors returned by GetLastError are:
>
> ```
> ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (2)
> ERROR_TIMEOUT (1460)
> ERROR_SUCCESS (0)
> ```
>
> ***The most appropriate response to any error returned by Shell_NotifyIcon is to sleep for a period of time and retry.***
>
> An explanation of why the error code may differ has been made by Paul Baker, paraphrased from http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell/msg/59235b293cbf5dfa and http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell/msg/73973287f15c03fc:
>
> Shell_NotifyIcon actually calls SetLastError(0) initially. After that, basically it uses FindWindow to find the tray notification window. If this fails, it will typically return ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Otherwise it sends a WM_COPYDATA message to the tray notification window, using SendMessageTimeout with a timeout of only 4 seconds. If that message returns zero, then Shell_NotifyIcon will fail with GetLastError returning zero.

Solution:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    ...
    if (!TrayMessage(hWnd, NIM_ADD)) 
        SetTimer(hWnd, IDT_TIMER1, 4000, (TIMERPROC) NULL);
    break;

case WM_TIMER:
    TrayMessage(hWnd, NIM_ADD);
    KillTimer(IDT_TIMER1);
    break;
```